# PHP regular expression will clean the element in XML feed

Tags: php, xml, preg-replace

I'm parsing XML feed which contains DESCRIPTION tag with html content like that:

```
<DESCRIPTION>
<![CDATA[ <p style="text-align: justify;">Lahodná příchuť stvořená pro ochucování vlastních liquidů od italského potravinářského výrobce Flavour Art.</p> <p style="text-align: justify;">Dávkování příchuti do liquidu je zcela individuální, doporučujeme zhruba 8 kapek na 10 ml nikotinové báze. Kažopádně tohle je na každém z nás jak moc intezivní příchuť vyžaduje, tudíž může dát kapek méně, ale i více. Samozřejmě všeho moc škodí, proto nedoporučujeme aplikovat více než 15 kapek na 10 ml nikotinové báze, samotná příchuť neobsahuje žádný nikotin. Více o míchání vlastních e-liquidů si můžete přečíst <strong><a title="Míchání e-liquidů" href="http://www.vaporism.cz/nez-zacneme-e-kourit/michame-si-vlastni-e-liquid-/">v našem manuálu ke snadnému míchání</a>.</strong></p> <p style="text-align: justify;"> Objem: 10ml</p> <p style="text-align: justify;"> Vyrobeno v Itálii.</p> ]]>
</DESCRIPTION>
```

But I need to remove only  elements

tags from this html content.. I already tried this:
`preg_replace('/\<a (.*?)\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/', '$2', $vap_description);` but it didn't worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

You should never trust simple regular expressions to strip-out HTML as it is potentially vulnerable.

Try parsing your XML and iterate over each node, applying https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier to it.